# How to view Firebase (FCM) message sends and delivery data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

We have an app in Android app-store. We enabled the "Firebase Cloud Messaging Data API" in firebase console.

According to its description, if we enable "Firebase Cloud Messaging Data API", it is supposed to provide additional information about **Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) message sends and deliveries.**

But we don't see any data around number of messages received by FCM and push notifications sent out.

Is there another way to figure out this data, by using fcmdata.googleapis.com directly?

Note, in our app we explicitly disable `firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated` but that should only impact data collected by Firebase analytics.

Is there way to get the data related to messages received by FCM and push notifications sent by FCM?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery#aggregated_delivery_data_via_the_data_api?

Comment: Thanks for that pointer @FrankvanPuffelen but is there no "console" -web page says "Firebase console message delivery reports" is there way to access it without enabling google analytics? Because this page says this --    "The reporting tools described in this page all require Google Analytics in order to function."